# Git: How to know the mode of a file in a commit

Tags: git

I would like to know the mode (x bit, symlink...) of a given file in a given past commit.

So far I have found a way with:

```
git format-patch --stdout SHA^..SHA -- FILE
```

This generates a mail within which it is possible to read/extract the mode information. Ex (with mode 120000 for a symlink):

```
From SHA DATE
From: USER MAIL
Date: DATE
Subject: COMMENT

---
FILE | 1 +
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 120000 FILE
diff --git a/FILE b/FILE
new file mode 120000
index 0000000..SSHA
--- /dev/null
+++ b/FILE
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+LINKTARGET
\ No newline at end of file
-- 
2.0.2
```

Is there a more straightforward way to get this kind of information?

Answer (score 3):

```
git ls-tree SHA:DIR
```

where *DIR* is the directory containing the file. It will give you listing like:

```
100755 blob 0123456789ABCDEF0123 FILE
```

where the first part is the mode, then type (blob, tree; not sure how submodule is called here), then the object ID and name. Grep for the file you are interested in.